mejorar macros de evento change en excel
quisiera saber si puedo mejorar mi macros que se encuentra en el evento change de la hoja de calculo de Excel, son códigos de cálculos básicos, además si me pudieran ayudar a reducir el código estaría muy agradecido.
de ante mano muchas gracias
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$L$5:$Y$9")) Is Nothing Then
        Sub todo()

Range("E22") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("E4:E21"))
Range("E23") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("E4:E19"))
Range("E24") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("E23") - WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("I4:I7")))
Range("i22") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("I4:I21"))
Range("I4") = Range("E23") * 0.1
Range("I6") = Range("E23") * 0.0127
Range("I5") = Range("EN10") * Range("EN11")
Range("I7") = Range("E23") * 0.006
Range("I25") = Range("E22") - Range("I22")
Range("I12") = Range("E24") * 0.03
Range("C7") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("EQ8") - (Range("EQ9"))) + Range("EN13") + Range("EN14") + Range("EN15") + Range("EN16")
'Range("E7") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("C7") * ((Range("E4") * 0.0077777)))
Range("C9") = Range("EQ9") + Range("EN17") + Range("EN18") + Range("EN19")
'Range("E9") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(((((Range("E4") / Range("C4")) * 7) / 45) * 1.3) * 1.5) * Range("C9")
'Range("E8") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(((((Range("E4") / Range("C4")) * 7) / 45) * 0.3)) * (Range("C8"))
Range("E9") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(((((Range("E4") / Range("C4")) * 7) / 44) * 1.3) * 1.5) * Range("C9")
Range("E8") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(((((Range("E4") / Range("C4")) * 7) / 44) * 0.3)) * (Range("C8"))
Range("E7") = WorksheetFunction.Sum((((Range("E4") / Range("C4")) * 7) / 44) * 1.5) * Range("C7")

End Sub

    End If
    
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub


¿Cuál es el error del código? ¿Qué problema tienes? No se aprecia ningún fallo ni queda claro cuál es el problema a corregir.
